# Background color for two spans, need to fill the space in between as with the same color

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/Deepu55555/pen/YBQxYd

HTML

```
<h1>Background Color</h1>

<div>Set a background color for a div element.</div>

<p>Set a <span>background</span> <span>color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #fefbd8;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #80ced6;
}

div {
  background-color: #d5f4e6;
}

span {
  background-color: #f18973;
}
```

I have two spans and assigned background color for both of them, is there any way I could fill the extra space with the same background color as the previous one? so that the background color doesn't separate between two spans?

Comment: use "<mark>" tag for this.

Comment: @MohitGupta I am unable to use the same when I have a block element as it only highlights the first element and leaves the second element in the next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just the following way of writing your code, then you can solve the issue:

```css
body {
  background-color: #fefbd8;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #80ced6;
}

div {
  background-color: #d5f4e6;
}

span {
  background-color: #f18973;
}
```

```html
<h1>Background Color</h1>

<div>Set a background color for a div element.</div>

<p>Set a <span>background </span><span>color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
```

This will work if you are working on static data, if you working with dynamic data then also, you can manage the spaces using this same representation.

---

**EDIT #1:**

Or instead of the following line:

```
<p>Set a <span>background </span><span>color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
```

You can use the following:

```
<p>Set a <span>background color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
```

---

**EDIT #2:**

Add the following to your CSS:

```
span::before{
  content: " ";
}
```

And change the following line:

```
<p>Set a <span>background </span> <span>color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
```

to (remove space between the spans):

```
<p>Set a <span>background </span><span>color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
```

Then, the solution would appear like the following:

```css
body {
  background-color: #fefbd8;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #80ced6;
}

div {
  background-color: #d5f4e6;
}

span {
  background-color: #f18973;
}

span::before {
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<h1>Background Color</h1>

<div>Set a background color for a div element.</div>

<p>Set a <span>background</span><span>color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
```

Comment: I think this is an interesting solution to solve such simple problem btw thanks will try doing this, do you have any other solution for the same instead of using a parent span ?

Comment: Do you want to use a coding solution for this issue? I can provide you with one, but it would be wastage of effort, since there is no point in making a simple solution complex.

Comment: If that uses javascript and CSS together please give let me know the alternative way of doing the same as I am dealing with block elements and this might not work in some cases.

Comment: Wait let me edit my answer, I have a way

Comment: Please check, I have added another solution

Answer (score 3):

You Can use One span for that two words so it will fill the color between space

```css
body {
  background-color: #fefbd8;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #80ced6;
}

div {
  background-color: #d5f4e6;
}

span {
  background-color: #f18973;
}
```

```html
<h1>Background Color</h1>

<div>Set a background color for a div element.</div>

<p>Set a <span>background color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
```

Comment: I am not looking for a solution which as a single span as that's not my requirement :( sorry.

Comment: you can also do the same by removing space between the span tag
like the following code

<p>Set a <span>background color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>

Answer (score 1):

Hope you need to avoid the empty space between "background" and "color". If so you can wrap those two "span" element with a parent "span".

```
<p>Set a <span>
<span>background</span> <span>color</span>    
</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the same thing by removing space between span

```css
body {
  background-color: #fefbd8;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #80ced6;
}

div {
  background-color: #d5f4e6;
}

span {
  background-color: #f18973;
}
```

```html
<h1>Background Color</h1>

<div>Set a background color for a div element.</div>

<p>Set a <span>background</span><span> color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
```